# How to sum with arguments in vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code:

```
Option Explicit


Function SumAboveV(column As Range)

Worksheets("Sheet16").Activate
Dim r As Range, rAbove As Range
Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
Set r = zelle.Offset(0, -2)
Set rAbove = Range(r.Offset(-1, 0), Cells(2, r.column))
column.Value = wf.Sum(rAbove)

End Function
```

All I want to have is to sum up all numbers I have in row B until the cell where I place the function so e.g. as you see in the attached screenshot I want to sum up all values from B2 until that cell and place the total value in row D.

I don't understand my mistake. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Like

```
Public Function SumUntil(ByRef rng As Range) As Double
    SumUntil = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(2, rng.Column), rng))
End Function
```

Usage:

[image: Example]

You add an optional start row for summing with

```
Public Function SumUntil(ByRef rng As Range, Optional ByVal startRow As Long = 3) As Double
    SumUntil = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(startRow, rng.Column), rng))
End Function
```

[image: Example 2]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating `Range` variables and all those manipulations, you can rely on R1C1 notation. Using R1C1 makes reference dynamic - no matter where you insert this formula in column D, it will get correct address. You just won't have to do extra manipulations.

```
zelle.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-2]:R2C[-2])"
```

Comment: More detail as to why this is the right answer would be preferable.

Comment: @JoeMcMahon Being inserted into column D, it doesn't need to calculate offsets, creating `Range` variables. It's just dynamic.

Comment: Could you add that to the answer? That would be helpful for others in the future to better understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something, but why not have just use sum in column D? if you use "=Sum($B2:B3)" Then drag that formula down to wherever. Then every cell in D would have a sum up until that row. It may be simpler than writing a whole macro for it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the formula:

```
=SUM($B$1:INDEX($B:$B,ROW()-1))
```

Placed in cell `B367` it returns the sum of `B1:B366` and doesn't give a circular reference warning.

Answer (score 0):

> All I want to have is to sum up all numbers I have in row B until the
>   cell where I place the function

then go this way:

```
Public Function SumAboveV() As Double
    SumAboveV = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("B2", Cells(Application.Caller.Row, "B")))
End Function
```

and you don't need to pass any parameter to your function, since `Application.Caller.Row` will get the row index of the "calling" cell

if you want it to update at any sheet recalculation then add `Application.Volatile` statement

```
Public Function SumAboveV() As Double
    Application.Volatile
    SumAboveV = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("B2", Cells(Application.Caller.Row, "B")))
End Function
```